# Upload image file in local pc using ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic3

### How to upload an image file in local machine as json file

---

I want to upload an image in json file, is it possible to upload an image file in json file. If it not possible please guide me how can i add that image file in asset folder. Can anyone help me out with this? I'm not able to figure it out how to solve this issue.

```js
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

    @Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
    })
    export class HomePage {

    base64Image: string;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private camera: Camera,public 
    http:HttpClient) {

    }

    openCamera(){
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
      saveToPhotoAlbum : true
    }
    
    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
     // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
     // If it's base64:
     this.base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
    }, (err) => {
     // Handle error
    }); 
    }

    openGallery(){
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
      saveToPhotoAlbum : true,
      sourceType : this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
    }
    console.log("gallery called....");
    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
     // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
     // If it's base64:
     this.base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
    }, (err) => {
     // Handle error
    }); 
    }

    uploadImage(){
    console.log("upload called....");
    let url = "assets/imgs/data/file.json";
    let postData = new FormData();
    postData.append('file',this.base64Image);
    let data:Observable<any> = this.http.post(url,postData);
    data.subscribe((result) => {
    console.log(result);
    });
    }

    }
```

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
 <button ion-button full (click) = "openCamera()">Take Photo</button>
 <button ion-button full (click) = "openGallery()">Open Gallery</button>
 <img [src] = "base64Image"/>
 <button ion-button full (click) = "uploadImage()">Upload Image</button>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: Removed quote markup from question

Comment: i didn't get you

Comment: Sorry, that was supposed to be a comment on my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's posible. You are saving images as string(base64).

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/

use methods like

> writeFile(path, fileName, text, options)

on your file.

> assets/imgs/data/file.json